# Official support for SE apps

Tags: support, feature-request

Is SE a company, or to put it another way, is it possible to develop apps for SE itself, rather than as a 3rd party?

I find it frustrating to get to a complete list of my sites, you have to go to user page and click 'more' under my accounts. this is necessary because we don't get notifications if you lose rep, and so I was thinking of making this page just one click. but I then thought this might be something SE would be interested in.

How would I go about proposing this to SE?

Comment: SE is a company.  Do you want to work for them?  Feature requests for the software can go on Meta.SE.